# How to use array.push correctly?

Tags: javascript

```
var send_value = [current_site_id, current_site_name, current_site_description];
console.log(send_value);
send_value = jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? send_value.push('add') : send_value.push('delete');
console.log(send_value);
```

The result is

> ["12", "qwrqweqwer", "qwreqwr"]
>  4

Where i'm wrong?

PS.
Sorry, my mistake was in `send_value =`, can not understand how it got there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `send_value = jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? send_value.push('add') : send_value.push('delete');` assigns the *return value* of `push` to `send_value`, it doesn't push anything. The return value is the new length of the array object, [as you can see in the specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7)

Try this:

```
send_value.push(jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? 'add' : 'delete');
```

Push the resulting value of your ternary
If you find it more readable, you could turn your ternary into an expression, rather then a statement:

```
(jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? send_value.push('add') : send_value.push('delete'));//<-- notice surrounding parentheses
```

But, frankly, if your concerned about readability, it's best to do away with ternaries all together IMHO.

Comment: The items *are* pushed in the array but he has lost a reference to the array

Comment: @Esailija: I left that out, for the OP to discover :P, that's why I linked to the specifications, and hinted at the return value being the _new_ length of the array object

Comment: my mistake was in `send_value =`... I don't know for what i use it, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`push` returns the length of the array after the pushes are done. Try this:

```
var send_value = [current_site_id, current_site_name, current_site_description];
console.log(send_value);
send_value.push( jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? 'add' : 'delete' );
console.log(send_value);
```

Additionally you should use an object not an array. `send_value.site_id` reads better than `send_value[0]`...

Comment: It should be mentioned that ternary expressions with side effects are considered bad practice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = jQuery(this).is(':checked') ? 'add' : 'delete';
    send_value.push(result);
```